# I try to do the UICollectionView in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uicollectionview

Please refer the idea on this link…
http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/

Would you for change some function to be swift Language 
Please refer whole data file

I only have problem with 2 functions, please help to change this two function into Swift?

File : AFViewController.m

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(AFTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cell setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:self index:indexPath.row];
    NSInteger index = cell.collectionView.tag;

    CGFloat horizontalOffset = [self.contentOffsetDictionary[[@(index) stringValue]] floatValue];
    [cell.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(horizontalOffset, 0)];
}
```

File: AFTableViewCell.m

```
-(void)setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:(id<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>)dataSourceDelegate index:(NSInteger)index
{
    self.collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate;
    self.collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate;
    self.collectionView.tag = index;
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: What are your tries to translated them?

Comment: what are you trying to do now?